# Javascript shows ids of both body and clicked elemnt on click event

Tags: javascript, html

I have one js function,say check(val). I call it on click event on body and one  tag. When I click on body it correctly shows id of body element. But,when when I click on , it shows ids of both  and body!

I just want to display id of  on click and on body's click event some other action to be executed.

My sample HTML code:

```
<body id="body" onclick="check(this.id);">
    <a href="#" id="ele" onclick="check(this.id)">Hello</div>
</body>
```

JS Code :

```
function check(val)
{
    if(val=="ele"){
    alert("element is clicked");
    }else if(val=="body"){
    alert("Body is clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html. The other articles about event handling a very good as well, you should read them.

Answer (score 4):

you need to `stop Propagation of event` using `event.stopPropagation()` method. already @StephenThomas mentioned this in comment of your question.

try this,

**HTML markup:**

```
<body id="body" onclick="check(event,this.id);">
    <a href="#" id="ele" onclick="check(event,this.id)">Hello</div>
</body>
```

**javascript code:**

```
function check(event, val) {
    if (val == "ele") {
        alert("element is clicked");
        event.stopPropagation();  //here we stop propagation of the event
    } else if (val == "body") {
        alert("Body is clicked");
    }
}
```

SEE THIS [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yigalavi/1/).

I hope this would help you...

Answer (score 1):

Every browser handles event bubbling differently. Some will show both and some will only show the link. You can change the function to fit every clicked element:

```
function check(val)
{
    alert("Clicked element type is: " + val.nodeName);
}
```

This way you don't need any id detection because you check the type of the node itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting both ids because when you click on the anchor you are also clicking on the body since the anchor is a child of the body element.

Answer (score 0):

**important note**:when you click on the anchor you are also clicking on the body

use  like this

```
  <body id="body" onclick="check(this);">

    <a href="#" id="ele" onclick="check(this);">Hello</a>
    </body>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function check(val)
    {
        if(val.id.toString()=="ele"){
        alert("element is clicked");
        }else if(val.id.toString()=="body"){
        alert("Body is clicked");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess in case of `body`, it's true, but you could have two elements that are not overlaying each other and a click on one of them would still trigger the handlers of each of them.